# How to apply DependencyProperty values to child user controls?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have multiple instances of the same custom user control in a StackPanel. Each instance needs the same DependencyProperty "ControlWidth". Instead of setting each user control with the same property, I want to set it only once in the parent StackPanel

```
 <StackPanel>
      <propwin:PropertyEditControl Label="First" ControlWidth="180" />
      <propwin:PropertyEditControl Label="First" ControlWidth="180" />
      ...
 </StackPanel>
```

I used to do this with Style properties

```
 <StackPanel>
      <StackPanel.Resources>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type propwin:PropertyEditControl}">
                  <Setter Property="ControlWidth" Value="180" />
             </Style>
       </StackPanel.Resources>

       <propwin:PropertyEditControl Label="First" />
       <propwin:PropertyEditControl Label="Second" />
       ...
 </StackPanel>
```

Update:
Thanks to  Anatoliy, who mention that my code (the one I showed here) should work. I now tracked down the problem. Inside my PropertyEditControl.xaml I define a validation style:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyModule.PropertyEditControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyModule">

 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyModule;component/UI/ResourceDictionaries/ResourceLibrary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="local:PropertyEditControl">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="PropertyNameStyle" TargetType="DockPanel">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ControlWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Left" />
        </Style>

...
```

If I remove the `<Style TargetType="local:PropertyEditControl">` style it works!

Comment: In `Style` properties are set the type of dependency property, this is one of the main conditions, in your case it should work. Show full code of `UserControl` with *`ControlWidth`* property.

Comment: *That doesn't work for non-style properties I guess* What does it means.. dp will works in all the Styles..

Comment: @Sankarann That was another way to ask if understood this principle correctly

Comment: That's fine.. is it working fine now? else still facing the issue?

Comment: *`If I remove the <Style TargetType="local:PropertyEditControl"> style it works!`* - this is because such a construction should be used outside of your `UserControl`. For example, in `<Window.Resources>` or in `App.xaml` file.

Comment: Now I know :-) Thanks. But you also wrote "should be", not "must be"

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my original approach should have worked. The reason why it hasn't was a misplaced Style Resource inside the user control. Anyway, the correct answer to my initial question is: To set a DependencyProperty value for multiple controls only once, you have to set it inside the container style definition:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type propwin:PropertyEditControl}">
              <Setter Property="ControlWidth" Value="180" />
         </Style>
     </StackPanel.Resources>

     <propwin:PropertyEditControl Label="First" />
     <propwin:PropertyEditControl Label="Second" />
     ...
</StackPanel>
```